# I have a 414(h) pension plan as a teacher in New Jersey. Am I permitted to also contribute yearly to an individual Ira?

Tags: united-states, ira, retirement

My husband is a teacher in New Jersey; 61 years of age. He has a pension plan listed on w-2 in box 14 (other). It is coded as 414(h). He asked the tax advise person at the school if he could still contribute maximum yearly amount to an individual Ira and was told yes. An accountant we know told us this was incorrect. Can he deduct the amount placed in individual Ira?

Comment: The title asks if *you* can take an IRA deduction. The text of the question asks if Hubby can. Please clarify.

Comment: Between all of you I believe you have answered my question. I believe my husband misunderstood the tax person at school- he may have asked if he could contribute rather than if he can use deduction. I had read about income table and I think that is what I need to look at. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

"Can he contribute" and "Can he deduct" are two different questions.

Yes, he can contribute.

But deduction issue may not be so clear-cut. Deduction of IRA contributions for someone who is covered by a retirement plan depends on income levels.

Filing for 2014 tax year - for married couple filing jointly, the phaseout starts at income levels of $96,000 and is complete at $116,000. So if you both are filing together and your income is above $116,000 (for both of you combined) then he cannot deduct the contributions.

If you each file separately, the phase-out kicks in immediately and is complete at $10,000.

In case of non-deductible contributions, you need to attach form 8606 to your tax return to keep track of the non-deductible basis. Unless you have some amounts in IRA already, it would be a good idea to convert all your non-deductible contributions to Roth IRA. Talk to your tax adviser about your options.

Comment: +1 - Updated the numbers. You had 2013 numbers in the answer. Up to you if you'd like to re-edit and add the phase out for non working spouse deductibility.

Comment: Do you mean "it would be a good idea to convert all your *non*-deductible contributions to Roth IRA"?

Comment: +1 of course. But let me add that since the accountant that the OP and her husband have talked to seems to be unaware of the rules, "Talk to your tax adviser about your options" seems to be advice that she cannot benefit from. Unless, of course, the accountant is a casual acquaintance who was not told all the facts (conversation at a party or in a social setting?) and not their tax adviser at all.

Comment: @DilipSarwate "an accountant we know told us" doesn't sound like a proper tax adviser. Its one thing to answer someone's casual question during a joint hike on Saturday, and another thing to give a proper advice in the office for which he/she is being paid.